# JAVA search list field

Tags: java, list, search, field

I searched how to do this, but didn't find anything like what. I'm not good in English so I didn't know how this thing is called. Please someone tell me how to create something like this or how this thing is called. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? this image can be lot of things... I recommend you to [start here](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20autocomplete%20jcombobox)

Comment: Thank you this is what I need.

Comment: Ignoring the engine of select the best match for a string inside a huge database, What you are looking is for an autocomplete dropdown combobox. [Here](http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html) you can see a nice example of how to create one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the SwingX library.

Example:

```
JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "One", "Two",
        "Three", "Four", "Five" });
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox);
```

If you want to do it yourself, read this: http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/